# How to implement TestNg reporting in keyword driven framework

Tags: java, frameworks, testng, reporting

I am trying to implement TestNG for reporting purpose in my keyword driven framework (Java). I need to publish execution time of each test cases (and step), pass/fail status of each test cases(and step) in my reports. TestNG does it automatically if there are separate methods for each test case. 
The problem that I'm facing is I'm running a loop for each test case, in that loop a method gets called to execute that particular test case. Now, in the called test case method, again a method gets called for each test step. How can I design my framework so that TestNG treats each test case/step as a new method and furnishes the execution time and pass/fail status of each test case/step.
I'm also open to any other suggestions by which I can implement the reporting module in my keyword-driven framework

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, its doable with some effort.  You can create a custom TestNG reporter, [similar to how I did it in this project](https://github.com/djangofan/testng-custom-report-example), and by doing that you can add a new column the test report, just as I added the "test name" column, and then you can put together the data you need and place it in that cell on the test row.

To store the timings, per method call, I would use Stopwatch from Apache commons-lang3 .

Comment: I used Apache Stopwatch for execution time but I'm still unable to implement the reporting part. I'm not getting any idea how you achieved it in your project. Can you please explain your approach a bit so that I can have a clear picture of what the code is doing?
It will be really a big help.

Comment: I had to implement a CustomReport.class (  https://github.com/djangofan/testng-custom-report-example/blob/master/src/main/java/qa/test/CustomReport.java  )  which is a copy of the original org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2.class  but modified by me to have different look and different structure.  Do a diff on the 2 above mentioned classes and that might make things clearer.